# .htaccess and RewriteRule expression

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have following urls domain/jcb-wine{number}.html and i need to rewrite them like domain/wines/{number}
I do something like this

```
RewriteRule ^jcb-wine([0-9][0-9])$ /wines/$
```

But this has no effect :(

my .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wine/([0-9]{2}) /jcb-wine$1.html
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be the other way round?

```
RewriteRule ^wine/([0-9]+) /jcb-wine$1.html
```

Comment: maybe i do it following the manual here http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html your code still does not a trick for me :(

Comment: I just checked and it does work for me. Maybe you don't have mod_rewrite on?

Comment: But do you have the apache module on?

Comment: yes its turned on and present, and when i visit http://jcbwines.com/jcb-wine1.html its still the same url

Comment: I modified the rewrite rule to accept any number of digits (your question suggested 2 digits exactly). The old URL will remain valid. Visit `/wine/1` to see whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

remove ^  оr write full uri like

```
RewriteRule ^/jcb-wine([0-9]+)/?$ /wines/$1
```